# SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName() is anonymousUser even after successful login

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I will try to keep this question as simple as possible because I suspect I am missing something simple in general.
I am having a Spring Security configuration and a login url. The login works through the standard security flow - authentication manager, password encoder, UserDetails, etc.
This flow works fine and I am able to successfully login.
After the login logic goes through and I execute `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();`
I successfully get the logged in user.

The problem is that on a following request (through Postman) I am getting `anonymousUser` once I am trying to get the currently logged user via `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();`.
I am aware that SecurityContextHolder.getContext() is per thread, so I guess there should be some way of sharing the logged in user throughout requests.
Any input will be much appreciated as I am sure I am missing something here but not really sure what :)

Answer (score 0):

I see the reason you have the issue is due to the fact that Spring Security's authentication information is only available within the same thread that performed the login.

This way if you make subsequent requests through Postman, each request is handled by a different thread, and the authentication information is not automatically propagated to those threads.

If you want to fix the issue, I can suggest you to enable session management in your Spring Security configuration. It will ensure that the authentication information is stored in a session and associated with the user's browser, allowing it to persist across multiple requests.